# How to print a bunch of integers with the same formatting?

Tags: c++, c++11, code-duplication, iomanip

I would like to print a bunch of integers on 2 fields with `'0'` as fill character. I can do it but it leads to code duplication. How should I change the code so that the code duplication can be factored out?

```cpp
#include <ctime>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

string timestamp() {

    time_t now = time(0);

    tm t = *localtime(&now);

    ostringstream ss;

    t.tm_mday = 9; // cheat a little to test it
    t.tm_hour = 8;

    ss << (t.tm_year+1900)
       << setw(2) << setfill('0') << (t.tm_mon+1) // Code duplication
       << setw(2) << setfill('0') <<  t.tm_mday
       << setw(2) << setfill('0') <<  t.tm_hour
       << setw(2) << setfill('0') <<  t.tm_min
       << setw(2) << setfill('0') <<  t.tm_sec;

    return ss.str();
}

int main() {

    cout << timestamp() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I have tried

```cpp
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, int i) {

    return s << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << i;
}
```

but it did not work, the `operator<<` calls are ambigous.

---

**EDIT** I got 4 awesome answers and I picked the one that is perhaps the simplest and the most generic one (that is, doesn't assume that we are dealing with timestamps). For the actual problem, I will probably use [`std::put_time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time) or [`strftime`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime) though.

Comment: Creating a new `ostream& operator<<` for `int` is a really bad idea. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yeah, I figured that out too. Any suggestions what to do instead?

Comment: if you are trying to format date/time you may want to check this out: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time

Comment: @zahir Awesome: could you post it as an answer? I would like to upvote it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a proxy for your string stream like this:

```
struct stream{
    std::ostringstream ss;
    stream& operator<<(int i){
        ss << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << i;
        return *this; // See Note below
    }
};
```

Then your formatting code will just be this:

```
stream ss;
ss << (t.tm_year+1900)
   << (t.tm_mon+1)
   << t.tm_mday
   << t.tm_hour
   << t.tm_min
   << t.tm_sec;

return ss.ss.str();
```

ps. Note the general format of my stream::operator<<() which does its work first, then returns something.

Comment: Upvoted, thanks! I am not quite sure I understand your note. Yes, you have to return a stream-like object so that the next `operator<<` can be called on it. My attempt also returned something, namely `std::ostream`.

Answer (score 5):

In C++20 you'll be able to do this with [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) in a less verbose way:

```
    ss << std::format("{}{:02}{:02}{:02}{:02}{:02}",
                      t.tm_year + 1900, t.tm_mon + 1, t.tm_mday,
                      t.tm_hour, t.tm_min, t.tm_sec);
```

and it's even easier with [the {fmt} library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) that supports `tm` formatting directly:

```
auto s = fmt::format("{:%Y%m%d%H%M%S}", t);
```

Answer (score 2):

The "obvious" solution is to use a manipulator to install a custom `std::num_put<char>` facet which just formats `int`s as desired.

The above statement may be a bit cryptic although it entirely describes the solution. Below is the code to actually implement the logic. The first ingredient is a special `std::num_put<char>` *facet* which is just a class derived from `std::num_put<char>` and overriding one of its `virtual` functions. The used facet is a filtering facet which looks at a flag stored with the stream (using `iword()`) to determine whether it should change the behavior or not. Here is the code:

```
class num_put
    : public std::num_put<char>
{
    std::locale loc_;
    static int index() {
        static int rc(std::ios_base::xalloc());
        return rc;
    }
    friend std::ostream& twodigits(std::ostream&);
    friend std::ostream& notwodigits(std::ostream&);

public:
    num_put(std::locale loc): loc_(loc) {}
    iter_type do_put(iter_type to, std::ios_base& fmt,
                     char fill, long value) const {
        if (fmt.iword(index())) {
            fmt.width(2);
            return std::use_facet<std::num_put<char> >(this->loc_)
                .put(to, fmt, '0', value);
        }
        else {
            return std::use_facet<std::num_put<char> >(this->loc_)
                .put(to, fmt, fill, value);
        }
    }
};
```

The main part is the `do_put()` member function which decides how the value needs to be formatted: If the flag in `fmt.iword(index())` is non-zero, it sets the width to `2` and calls the formatting function with a fill character of `0`. The width is going to be reset anyway and the fill character doesn't get stored with the stream, i.e., there is no need for any clean-up.

Normally, the code would probably live in a separate translation unit and it wouldn't be declared in a header. The only functions really declared in a header would be `twodigits()` and `notwodigits()` which are made `friend`s in this case to provide access to the `index()` member function. The `index()` member function just allocates an index usable with `std::ios_base::iword()` when called the time and it then just returns this index. The *manipulators* `twodigits()` and `notwodigits()` primarily set this index. If the `num_put` facet isn't installed for the stream `twodigits()` also installs the facet:

```
std::ostream& twodigits(std::ostream& out)
{
    if (!dynamic_cast<num_put const*>(
             &std::use_facet<std::num_put<char> >(out.getloc()))) {
        out.imbue(std::locale(out.getloc(), new num_put(out.getloc())));
    }
    out.iword(num_put::index()) = true;
    return out;
}

std::ostream& notwodigits(std::ostream& out)
{
    out.iword(num_put::index()) = false;
    return out;
}
```

The `twodigits()` manipulator allocates the `num_put` facet using `new num_put(out.getloc())`. It doesn't require any clean-up because installing a facet in a `std::locale` object does the necessary clean-up. The original `std::locale` of the stream is accessed using `out.getloc()`. It is changed by the facet. In theory the `notwodigits` could restore the original `std::locale` instead of using a flag. However, `imbue()` can be a relatively expensive operation and using a flag should be a lot cheaper. Of course, if there are lots of similar formatting flags, things may become different...

To demonstrate the use of the manipulators there is a simple test program below. It sets up the formatting flag `twodigits` twice to verify that facet is only created once (it would be a bit silly to create a chain of `std::locale`s to pass through the formatting:

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << "some-int='" << 1 << "' "
              << twodigits << '\n'
              << "two-digits1='" << 1 << "' "
              << "two-digits2='" << 2 << "' "
              << "two-digits3='" << 3 << "' "
              << notwodigits << '\n'
              << "some-int='" << 1 << "' "
              << twodigits << '\n'
              << "two-digits4='" << 4 << "' "
              << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Could you please expand on that? It is not that "obvious" to me :(

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know. I will wait for your answer!

Comment: Upvoted, I greatly appreciate your efforts! I don't accept any answers yet, I may get other answers and the existing answers may be upvoted as well.

Answer (score 2):

Besides formatting integers with [`std::setw`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) / [`std::setfill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill) or [`ios_base::width`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/width) / [`basic_ios::fill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/fill), if you want to format a date/time object you may want to consider using [`std::put_time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time) / [`std::gettime`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time)

Answer (score 1):

For convenient output formatting you may use [`boost::format()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/format/) with `sprintf`-like formatting options:

```
#include <boost/format.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int i1 = 1, i2 = 10, i3 = 100;
    std::cout << boost::format("%03i %03i %03i\n") % i1 % i2 % i3; 
    // output is: 001 010 100
}
```

Little code duplication, additional implementation effort is marginal.

---

If all you want to do is output formatting of your timestamp, you should obviously use [`strftime()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime). That's what it's made for:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

std::string timestamp() {
    char buf[20];
    const char fmt[] = "%Y%m%d%H%M%S";
    time_t now = time(0);
    strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), fmt, localtime(&now));
    return buf;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << timestamp() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But you don't need boost for that: `snprintf(buffer, 15, "%d%02d%02d%02d%02d%02d", t.tm_year+1900, t.tm_mon+1, t.tm_mday, t.tm_hour, t.tm_min, t.tm_sec);`. I personally don't like the C style formatting

Comment: Upvoted! I did not know `strftime` was part of the standard. I knew about it but I thought it was only in POSIX.

Answer (score 0):

`operator<<(std::ostream& s, int i)` is "ambiguous" because such a function already exists.

All you need to do is give that function a signature that doesn't conflict.

Comment: Could you give a working example, preferably an operator function?

Comment: And how do you intend to do that, Drew?